# Is it possible to use a IR proximity sensor as a dust optical sensor?

Tags: infrared

I'm doing an automatized-ish windshield wiper project, which requires some kind of dust sensor. I have an IR proximity sensor and I could only find people using it for rain detection on windshields. 
Can I use it or it's sensibility isn't enough?

Comment: This is a very broad question, and isn't specifically about Arduino. At the very least you should edit your question to include the specific sensor you are using, as well as links to projects that use that sensor for rain detection.

Comment: I'm just curious:  Why does windshield wiper needs a dust sensor. Is it because you want to find out whether it is so dry that there is dust in the air? In any way I don't think a IR proximity sensor is the right chose to detect rain and I'm sure it can not detect dust, mist or fog.

Comment: If you want to detect dust, consider the wikipedia description of how an optical smoke detector works.  But it really sounds like you want to do something else entirely.  Edit both the title and question to make it clear what you want to do.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I think the OP doesn't want to detect dust in the air so much as debris on the windshield.

Answer (score 1):

Dust sensors are available that basically use an IR light source (LED) and an IR detector (photodiode).  However they don't work by the dust breaking the beam as you would expect.

Instead they operate in a specially shaped chamber that prevents the IR light from reaching the detector under normal circumstances, but the detector is able to observe the area where the light *is*.

Then any dust that floats into that specially shaped chamber (often heated by a resistor to keep air circulating through it) reflects the IR light and the detector can see those sparkles and glints of light from the dust.

As you can imagine such an arrangement which relies on dust to be floating and moving to reflect the light right can't really be used when the dust is static on a windscreen.

However, if you are in an exceedingly dusty area it could be possible to position the light source one side of the windscreen at some distance and have the detector inside. Modulate the IR LED to some carrier frequency so that you can isolate it from the background light in the detector using a band-pass filter at the carrier frequency, and the strength of the signal received could indicate the reduction in light passing through the glass. How accurate this would be or reliable I cannot comment, but it may be something worth experimenting with.

Answer (score 0):

Some glass may reflect back infrared rays. In that case this sensor would be useless.
Also even if the glass is transparent to IR the dust particles on the wind wind are too small that the longer wavelength IR would simply diffract around the periphery or those particles and won't reflect back.

May I suggest you use some kind of optical sensor.
Image processing methods would be very useful in identifying the quantity of dust on the wind shield.